# Integrate http apache with kaazing gateway

Tags: apache, xmpp, kaazing

I am running an app on http apache 2.4 through which I am trying to connect to a kaazing gateway. I have followed the 
instructions that are found in kaazing site at "setup-guide.html#webserver_integrate" section, but the connection keeps failing: the Mozilla console prints:

```
 TypeError: this._socket is undefined, 4146 XmppClient.js
```

I changed the `<allow origin>` with an `*`. I would like to ask whether I should make any changes on the configuration file of apache.

Comment: what do you mean by falling?

Comment: from mozila console I get, 'TypeError: this._socket is undefined, 4146 XmppClient.js'

Comment: can you give as a link to the instructions you are following?

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. The instructions are : http://tech.kaazing.com/documentation/xmpp/3.5/about/setup-guide.html#webserver_integrate . Kaazing localhost:8001/ works fine and so apache. The problem is when a connection is attempted from the web-app to the gateway kaazing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed it to work. I made a new install of kaazing gateway. In gateway-config.xml at the GATEWAY_HOME/conf/ I changed the value of the gateway.hostname with my internal ip and set the

> *

at

`<cross-site-constraint>
      <allow-origin>*</allow-origin>
</cross-site-constraint>`

in service with type: xmpp.proxy and this time worked! Also I changed  '

> *

with the

> `http://localhost:80`

(http apache) and also worked. I don't know why didn 't it work before.
Thanks for trying to help!